# Play winsound at a specific condition

Tags: python, animation, audio, tkinter

I am working on Tkinter to animate a diver jumps into the water.
I need the program plays a sound the moment he touches the water.
Here is **part** of my code but it didn't work.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from math import *
    import winsound, sys
    def beep():
        winsound.PlaySound('death1.wav' , winsound.SND_FILENAME)

    def animate():            
        nonlocal x,y,flag,t,i
        t=i*dt
        i=i+1
        if y<=PosYe+20:     #we define the water level = PosYe+20
            Canevas.coords(plongeur,x,y)
            x,y=x,y+g*t*dt*m1  
            if y==PosYe+20 :
                beep()
```

I tried this (just to verify if it can play the sound), it plays the sound everytime it calculates it's new position. So i wonder if i can't write a condition in a condition in this situation.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from math import *
    import winsound, sys
    def beep():
        winsound.PlaySound('death1.wav' , winsound.SND_FILENAME)

    def animate():            
        nonlocal x,y,flag,t,i
        t=i*dt
        i=i+1
        if y<=PosYe+20:     #we define the water level = PosYe+20
            Canevas.coords(plongeur,x,y)
            x,y=x,y+g*t*dt*m1  
            beep()
```

I need some advice to write the condition correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate the update position part and the feedback part.
Also you have to be sure that updating `y` position falls in the value `PosYe+20` because we can have `old_y < PosYe+20 < new_y`
Finally, you can add a flag that is initialised with `True` but switched to `False` once you have a collision.

You can try this code:

```
if y < PosYe + 20:     #we define the water level = PosYe+20
    Canevas.coords(plongeur,x,y)
    x,y=x,y+g*t*dt*m1  

elif flag and PosYe + 20 <= y :
    beep()
    flag = False
```